# Trying to make a "solid" block in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So i want my player to not be able to pass through the block, but it teleports to the other side, any idea why? here's my code:

```
def update(self, collidable):
    self.rect.x += self.hspeed

    collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
    for collided_object in collision_list:
        if (self.hspeed > 0):
            # right direction
            self.rect.right = collided_object.rect.left

        elif (self.hspeed < 0):
            # left direction
            self.rect.left = collided_object.rect.right

    self.rect.y += self.vspeed

    collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)   
    for collided_object in collision_list:
        if (self.vspeed > 0):
         # down direction
            self.rect.bottom = collided_object.rect.up

        elif (self.vspeed < 0):
            # up direction
            self.rect.top = collided_object.rect.bottom
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: What are your inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs?

Comment: What is `collided_object.rect.up`?

Comment: @Peter Wood collidable_objects = pygame.sprite.Group()
collidable_objects.add(another_block) collided_object.rect.up should refer to the upside of the collided object

Comment: What about `rect.top`?

Comment: that should also refer to the top... hmmm i think one of them is wrong

Comment: @PeterWood   I changed it and now it is just exactly the same i teleport through the block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the last answer. Here's one that should fix your code.
The new code is:

```
def update(self, collidable):
    self.rect.x += self.hspeed

    collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
    for collided_object in collision_list:
        if (self.hspeed > 0):
            # right direction
            self.rect.left = collided_object.rect.right # rect.right and rect.left swapped

        elif (self.hspeed < 0):
            # left direction
            self.rect.right = collided_object.rect.left # rect.right and rect.left swapped

    self.rect.y += self.vspeed

    collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)   
    for collided_object in collision_list:
        if (self.vspeed > 0):
         # down direction
            self.rect.bottom = collided_object.rect.up

        elif (self.vspeed < 0):
            # up direction
            self.rect.top = collided_object.rect.bottom
```

The lines I changed were in the self.hspeed collision. When you hit one side, instead of sticking to that side, you were locking to the other side of the cube. In short I swapped rect.left and rect.right, but you could have swapped the > 0 and < 0 but I wanted to keep that in the right odder so it looked nicer...

Comment: Ik :( but it was a repeat of one of my other answers. You can still find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209678/trying-to-make-a-solid-block-in-pygame-but-it-doesnt-work/32253474#32253474

Comment: This code is really handy and i learned a lot out of your other code! :) YOU ARE ME HERO!